# Changing footer image size displaces adjacent images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am making the footer of my homepage that will contain the icons of three of my profiles and I'm using a javascript snippet to increase the size of the images when the cursor is brought on them and decrease it when the cursor is out. The images are to be displayed horizontally, next to one another *(inline-block*).

Although the script works fine, I'm having an issue with the HTML: when I hover over the first image in the row, its size increases but the other images get displaced from their position, i.e., the entire row gets disrupted.

I want the images to be independently changing their sizes upon the occurrence of the mouse events.

Here's the footer code:

```
<center><footer>

      <div style="display:inline-block; height:40px; width:40px;">
      <img style="vertical-align:center;" src="https://i.imgur.com/e9l6jhU.png"
          id="0" height="30" width="30" onmouseover="footerimg2(0)" 
          onmouseout="footerimg1(0)" ></img>
      </div>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

      <div style="display:inline-block; height:40px; width:40px;">
      <img style="vertical-align:center;" src="https://i.imgur.com/RvAl3ob.png"
          id="1" height="30" width="30" onmouseover="footerimg2(1)" 
          onmouseout="footerimg1(1)" ></img>
    </div>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <div style="display:inline-block; height:40px; width:40px;">
      <img style="vertical-align:center;" src="https://i.imgur.com/vYUYQw9.png"
          id="2" height="30" width="30" onmouseover="footerimg2(2)" 
          onmouseout="footerimg1(2)" ></img>
    </div>


</footer></center>
```

The javascript, in case it's relevant:

```
<script>

    function footerimg2(id){
        var x = document.getElementById(id);
        x.width = 40;
        x.height = 40;
    }

    function footerimg1(id){
        var x = document.getElementById(id);
        x.width = 30;
        x.height = 30;
    }

</script>
```

### Here's the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2dj4yvt/)

**How do I make the images resize independently, without making the other images move?**

Comment: try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2dj4yvt/1/)

Comment: @ShadowFiend It works, but wouldn't an answer be more helpful for everyone?

Comment: Yeah.. i was going to.. haha..

Comment: Please check my answer for a pure CSS based solution which is a better performer than JS based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `position:absolute;`

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; height:40px; width:40px;">
  <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="https://i.imgur.com/e9l6jhU.png" id="0" height="30" width="30" onmouseover="footerimg2(0)" onmouseout="footerimg1(0)" />
</div>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<div style="display:inline-block; height:40px; width:40px;">
  <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="https://i.imgur.com/RvAl3ob.png" id="1" height="30" width="30" onmouseover="footerimg2(1)" onmouseout="footerimg1(1)" />
</div>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<div style="display:inline-block; height:40px; width:40px;">
  <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="https://i.imgur.com/vYUYQw9.png" id="2" height="30" width="30" onmouseover="footerimg2(2)" onmouseout="footerimg1(2)" />
</div>

<script>
  function footerimg2(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    x.width = 40;
    x.height = 40;
  }

  function footerimg1(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    x.width = 30;
    x.height = 30;
  }
</script>
```

Here is the [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y2dj4yvt/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go for a pure `CSS` based cleaner solution which performs better than `JS` based animations? You can also alter smooth transition time by changing the transition duration which is currently set to 500ms in the snippet.

```css
.icon{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
}

.icon img{
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
max-width: 100%;
position: absolute;
padding: 5px;
transition:all linear 500ms;
}


.icon:hover img{
height:40px;
width:40px;
}
```

```html
<footer>

      <div class="icon">
      <img id="0" src="https://i.imgur.com/e9l6jhU.png"/>
      </div>

      <div class="icon">
      <img id="1" src="https://i.imgur.com/RvAl3ob.png"/>
    </div>


    <div class="icon">
      <img id="2" src="https://i.imgur.com/vYUYQw9.png"/>
    </div>


</footer>
```

Comment: I actually figured it out later on that the same thing can be done better with CSS. Thanks for this.

Comment: I hope this solution deserves to be the correct answer.